# How do I handle JavaScript Fetch errors?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception, fetch-api

If a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) call fails in Chrome, then the only error details that I get back is

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

How do I display an informative error message to the end user in this case?

Specifically:

**Is it possible to get any details about why fetch failed?**

For example, if the server crashed, Chrome DevTools might log a console message of net:ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, but there appears to be no way to access this from JavaScript.

As far as I can tell, the answer is no; I assume this is for security reasons, to avoid letting malicious JS find out which sites are and aren't accessible by inspecting error messages.

**Is it possible to distinguish fetch errors from other `TypeError`s?**

If I can't get error details, I'd like to at least replace the horribly vague "Failed to fetch" with an informative "Failed to access the web site; please try again later" message, and I'd like to do this without any risk of displaying that message for other `TypeError`s.

The only solution I've found here is to check the actual `message` to see if it's `"Failed to fetch"`. This is obviously browser-specific; it works in Chrome, it seems like it will work in any user language of Chrome, and other browsers would need their own testing and handling.

Comment: `TypeError` seems like...really the wrong error type. Strange.

Comment: `.catch` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @JaromandaX - `.catch` works, but I'd like to get error details if possible (my first question), and to avoid incorrectly catching other `TypeError`s as fetch errors, I feel like I either have to put the `.catch` _very_ close to `fetch` (so no other errors can occur, thus losing flexibility in how I structure my promises) or rely on browser-specific behavior like the text of the fetch `message` (my second question).

Comment: I meant does handling the error in `.catch` stop the output to console (I take it that's where this error is showing)

Comment: The `TypeError: Failed to fetch` message is all you get in the `.catch` so you'll have to do some fancy footwork to change that to a meaningful message - the `.catch` can be at the end of the chain, doesn't matter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems likely that there aren't any more details for networking/permission/input problems.

> Is it possible to distinguish fetch errors from other TypeErrors?

Yes, you just need to `catch` only the the errors from the `fetch` call:

```
fetch(…)
.catch(err => new FetchError(err))
.…

class FetchError extends Error {
    constructor(orig) {
        super();
        this.message = "fetch error";
        this.details = orig;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth checking the protocol of the fetched url. Calling https:// on an http:// site can cause this error

Comment: Also, checking whether your `4XX` and `5XX` responses are not returning an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header could also be the cause.